# Improve match with functions Ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm learning Ocaml and I want to replace my old habits that come from C, Java....With PF habits.
I was use to verify conditions with "`if`...`else`..." statements.
I saw that also Ocaml provides them but I would like to replace them with `match ... with` or other PF typical statements.

My problem is that I'm missing some importants stuff like, in this code :

```
let find_max random  = 
  let rec support rlist max =
  match rlist with 
  | [] -> max
  | hd :: tl -> if hd > max then support tl hd else support tl max
let max = support random (List.hd random)
!max

let a = [1;2;3];
print_string "max element in list is : "
print_int (find_max a);
print_string "\n"
```

I want to avoid using `if...else` statements and changing them with some PF typical statements.
How can I do this?

Last one : `let max = support random (List.hd random)` is outside support but within `find_max`, how can I highlight this ?

P.S. : The code doesn't work, syntax error on `let max = support random (List.hd random)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, regarding the syntax errors, unless it is a toplevel declaration, the construct is `let x = e1 in e2`. (Notice the `in` keyword.) Moreover, sequences of statements are separated by semi-colons, which is just syntactic sugar for `let () = e1 in e2`.

Second, `if then else` is a perfectly idiomatic OCaml construct. Removing it will not make the code any clearer. In your case, I guess you could replace it with `when`.

```ml
let find_max random =
  let rec support rlist max =
    match rlist with
    | [] -> max
    | hd :: tl when hd > max -> support tl hd
    | hd :: tl -> support tl max in
  let max = support random (List.hd random) in
  max

let () =
  let a = [1;2;3] in
  print_string "max element in list is : ";
  print_int (find_max a);
  print_string "\n"
```

Comment: It worked than you! What is "when" and when I should use it?

Comment: See http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#sss:guards-in-pattern-matchings